# Disable HTML5 input using php

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I gt a php form script that allow user to input data into database but then there is another script that allow the user to edit the data in database using the same form script. My problem is when i want to edit the data, i want to disable certain input field from the form script that don't allow user to make changes. Can anyone teach me how?

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow is the right platform for this.

Comment: We can help you, but it would be easier if you could show us the relevant bit of code.  The easiest way would be to set a flag variable, `blnEdit` to true if you are editing.  Then only offer the `<input>` if the flag is false, otherwise just display the field's data.

Comment: do you mean adding the word "disabled" to the input field? cause that's all you need to do to prevent it from being altered

Comment: @KaiQing  yup. I want to change the attribute for the input field to disable or readonly using php. Is this possible?

Comment: hmm..maybe my question are not clear. I gt a form.php and edit.php and all input field in form.php allow user to enter something but when i run the edit.php that include form.php, i want to disable some input field.

Comment: you don't need php to add the disabled attribute. Unless you are asking for something like this: `<input name="something" type="text" value="<?php echo $var; ?>" <?php echo $editing ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>>`

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions.
You can set a flag by start the EDIT and check of this flag by START-EDIT. Quick'n dirty.

But you can lock the TUPLES for everyone - when not remove the flag

Answer (score 0):

In your database (setting table) make new column named "editmode".

And in your editor page you can define "editmode" value.

For users check "editmode" value from database:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($editmode_check)) 
{
$editmode= $row['editmode'];
}

if ($editmode==1) {
echo "Admin on Edit or ...";
} else {
... the page ...
}
```